# Functionality of FindMaximumFlow

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

I know that the superseeded function NetworkFlow (needs Combinatorica) uses Goldberg-Tarjan's Push-Relabel-Algorithm but i cant find any information on Mathematica's built-in-function ([`FindMaximumFlow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html)). How does it work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Have you asked Wolfram Support about this?  In my experience they will usually provide the references (provided that the developer cooperates...)  If you get a response, please post an answer here.