# Seemingly incorrect answer for FindMaximumFlow

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to solve a simple maximum flow problem ("workers" to "jobs") but the solution is seemingly incorrect, reporting that one edge is included (whereas a 1:1 assignment is possible). See screenshot.

```
    g = Graph[{"W1" -> "J3", "W2" -> "J1", "W2" -> "J2", "W3" -> "J2", 
   "W3" -> "J3"}]; 
    vc = ConstantArray[1, Length[VertexList[g]]];
    F = FindMaximumFlow[g, {"W1", "W2", "W3"}, {"J1", "J2", "J3"}, 
   "OptimumFlowData", VertexCapacity -> vc];
    {F, F["FlowGraph"]}
```

Interestingly, when I re-run, I sometimes get the correct answer, perhaps indicating it is a non-deterministic algorithm?

[image]

Comment: It seems to have been a problem for a long time, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/findmaximumflow-generates-a-weird-result, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86439/functionality-of-findmaximumflow.

Comment: Ah thanks - missed these. Appreciate it.

Comment: OK in version 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: So is there a reliable alternative to computing maximum network flows?